# Load liquibase classpath failed

Tags: jhipster

I generate app thanks to jhipster but when I run it I have the following error:

`.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.3\liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist:  .m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.3\lib\snakeyaml-1.13.jar`

The error happens in my IDE and when I run mvnw.

I can't find any solutions or workarounds.

Answer (score 4):

Ok it seems that in fact my application failed to start cause my application-dev.yml was malformatted. But the error message what really not explicite and believed that the error come from the liquibase classpath.

Comment: My file format is ok, get this error. What did you change?

Comment: Sry, it was a long time ago .... But I think it was just a yaml format issue for me.

Comment: you helped me after 2 days of trying to find the problem... yaml format sucks